# Hibernate java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm trying to create a hibernate query that will return some data, In my persistence class, I have a join mapped as @OneToMany for an object:

```
//bi-directional many-to-one association to TransactionDetail
@OneToMany(mappedBy="pallet")
private List<TransactionDetail> transactionDetails;
```

When I try to get the list as a whole (I need all the fields from it), I get the exception, I'm trying to do it like this:

```
ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
projectionList.add(Projections.property("idPallet"), "idPallet");
projectionList.add(Projections.property("type"), "type");
projectionList.add(Projections.property("sourceCode"), "sourceCode");
projectionList.add(Projections.property("registeredDate"), "registeredDate");
//error caused by next line    
projectionList.add(Projections.property("transactionDetails"), "transactionDetails"); 

Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Pallet.class, "pallet");
criteria.createAlias("pallet.transactionDetails", "transactionDetails",JoinType.INNER_JOIN);


criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Pallet.class));
```

Any idea what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Could please you share the stacktrace of the error?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to select some transactionDetails columns and not just the table

Exemple if your TransactionDetails entity has a `date` column

```
projectionList.add(Projections.property("transactionDetails.date"), "transactionDetailsDate");
```

2. You won't be able to transform to a `Pallet`.class (and it's not a good idea to use domain object as DTO)

You will have to create a DTO like a `PalletDTO` which will have all the fields of your projection :

- idPallet
- type
- sourceCode
- registeredDate
- transactionDetailsDate